# Check if background music is already playing

Tags: ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

There may not be a easy way of doing this outside of using a `NSUSERDEFAULT` but is there a way to check if the background music is already playing?

I am using

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"game_loop.mp3" loop:YES];
```

So is there a way to see if the value is already `game_loop.mp3` ? So I am looking to check if the file name is already playing so it doesn't reset when the view is loaded.

I have several background music files that load at certain points so can't just put it in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check one of the `baseURL`, `absoluteString` or `absoluteURL` properties of the currently loaded URL in the `[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance]`.

```
[[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] backgroundTrackURL] absoluteString]
```

Comment: This comes back as null even though background music is playing?

Comment: Did you also try baseURL and absoluteURL?

Comment: Fixed it. Put it in viewdidLoad which must have called it too soon

Comment: I get `///Users/oddpanda/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/1F16BA6B-ADD6-427D-BC71-C34252C606B3/PocketPanda.app/stable-boy.mp3` ... Is there anyway to only get `stable-boy.mp3` ?

Comment: Did you try all 3 properties (baseURL, absoluteString or absoluteURL)? Pick the one that has the friendliest format then parse the string.